# how to fix this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 34: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-2.7

I´m trying to code Euler, can you tell me what I am doing wrong, please?
i think the problem is when i want to use the lambda function, but i am not sure if it is that the problem.
When i run the program, it appears an error that says something about UnicodeDecodeError

```
from sympy import *

import numpy

from math import *

print 'Binvendio al programa de ecuaciones diferenciales resueltas por el método de Euler'

h=float(raw_input('Defina su ancho de banda: '))


new_h=h

x_i=int(raw_input('Defina su valor de x inicial: '))

x_f=int(raw_input('Defina el valor de x hasta el que se desea llegar: '))

y_0=int(raw_input('¿A qué valor está sujeto y0?'))

funcion=input('Introduzca la función:')

x,y=symbols('x y')

evaluar=lambda x,y:eval(funcion)

while new_h<x_f:

    new_h+=h

    r=evaluar(x_i,y_0)

    y_new=y_0+h*r

    y_0=y_new

    x_i+=h
```